# How to choose a random proper coloring

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, graph-colorings

I am studying proper colorings of complete bipartite graphs and I'd like to be able to pick a random proper coloring and the compute some things about it.

Recall that a proper coloring of a complete bipartite graph is precisely a latin rectangle where the $(i,j)$ entry is the color on the edge from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$.

My questions are generally of the form "for a large $m$ and $n$, is there a positive probability that the random proper coloring of $K_{m,n}$ has a copy of the subgraph $H$ which has a specific coloring?"

Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this paper: http://cs.anu.edu.au/~Brendan.McKay/papers/randomlatin.pdf ?  It seems to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I did not know of this paper.  After a cursory read through it is not clear how to use their algorithm to answer questions, like what is the probability of having a copy of subgraph $H$ that has all different colors.  Is it clear to you how to proceed using tools of probability?

In either case I will read through it in detail soon.   Thanks agian.